# Why can't I post to certain mailing lists via Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups, mailing-list

I'm unable to reply to any topic in the [llvm-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/llvm-dev) mailing list on Google Groups. I fail to see a *Reply to* button.

[image: Screenshot of Google Groups UI]
<sup>Link for bigger image: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD7HL.png)</sup>

Is there any way to check whether replying directly via Google Groups is disabled?

I see no *Reply-to* button or even a *Post* button.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to make your question clearer?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check under the *About* link:
[image: Group message list]

The group settings specifies that only managers may post:
[image: Screenshot of group settings]

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it was a permissions problem but couldn't find the group settings. I switched to nabble.com which under-the-hood deals with the mailman server and just shows me an asynchronous forum-like posting mode

Comment: Aha. I suspect Google Groups by default disables posting for mailing lists that are not created with Google Groups, e.g. external Mailman lists.